# What do the colons in the following Python code do?

Tags: python

This code is from the python tutorial documents - [4.7.7. Function Annotations](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/controlflow.html#function-annotations):

```
def f(ham: 42, eggs: int = 'spam') -> "Nothing to see here":
     print("Annotations:", f.__annotations__)
     print("Arguments:", ham, eggs)
```

I don't know what the colons (`:`) after "ham" and "eggs" do. Please explain to me.

Comment: Uhm, you already linked to the part of the docs that explain it?

Comment: Not to be a jerk but the answer is literally in the link you provided. "Function annotations are completely optional, arbitrary metadata information about user-defined functions. Neither Python itself nor the standard library use function annotations in any way; this section just shows the syntax. Third-party projects are free to use function annotations for documentation, type checking, and other uses."

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the answer is linked within the question itself.

Comment: See also [PEP-3107](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/).

Comment: If it helps, this appears to be a relatively new feature to Python - 2.x doesn't support it.

Comment: @MarkRansom yep, new in 3.0 per the PEP I just linked to.

Comment: Wait, I read it but I did not get it. What they are for? I don't see it mentioned in the text. Please do point me where it is. English is not my native so I could have misunderstood something

Comment: @MattDMo has it occurred to you that the documentation is not clear enough in this case? The example especially goes out of its way to be confusing.

Comment: @ttriet204 have you read the PEP I just linked to? It explains fully what they are and what they are for.

Comment: The rationale is explained in the PEP linked by @jonrsharpe. It's basically a way to add arbitrary metadata to function arguments and/or return values.

Comment: It’s literally just a way to attach objects to functions, arguments and other stuff. You could use it for documentation, validation, or just to add meaningless data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's basically a way to add arbitrary metadata to function arguments and/or return values.  --Lukas Graf

It’s literally just a way to attach objects to functions, arguments and other stuff. You could use it for documentation, validation, or just to add meaningless data.  --poke

Also see: [PEP-3107](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/)

**From the documentation directly:**

> *Function annotations* are completely optional, arbitrary metadata
>   information about user-defined functions. Neither Python itself nor
>   the standard library use function annotations in any way; this section
>   just shows the syntax. Third-party projects are free to use function
>   annotations for documentation, type checking, and other uses.
>
> Annotations are stored in the `__annotations__` attribute of the
>   function as a dictionary and have no effect on any other part of the
>   function. Parameter annotations are defined by a colon after the
>   parameter name, followed by an expression evaluating to the value of
>   the annotation. Return annotations are defined by a literal `->`,
>   followed by an expression, between the parameter list and the colon
>   denoting the end of the `def` statement. The following example has a
>   positional argument, a keyword argument, and the return value
>   annotated with nonsense:
>
> ```
> >>> def f(ham: 42, eggs: int = 'spam') -> "Nothing to see here":
> ...     print("Annotations:", f.__annotations__)
> ...     print("Arguments:", ham, eggs)
> ...
> >>> f('wonderful')
> Annotations: {'eggs': <class 'int'>, 'return': 'Nothing to see here', 'ham': 42}
> Arguments: wonderful spam
> ```

Comment: This is a verbatim cut-and-paste of the documentation the OP already linked to.

Comment: Yes it is.  Combined with the useful comments and the relevant and more useful PEP link.

Comment: Thank you, I got it now. The PEP-3107 document was very thorough!